# liclipse theme and mysterious line in the middle

Tags: eclipse, themes, pydev

I installed LiClipse and Darktheme, there's a weird vertical line in the middle of the source code window I can't get rid off.

Infact, eclipse with pydev and theme applied also had this mysterious line, what is this used for and how do I mute it?

[image: what is line and how do I get rid of it?]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That looks like the Print Margin indicator. You can disable it and/or change it's color via **Preferences** > **Editors** > **Text Editors**.

[image]